# iterator for map

Tags: c++, iterator, multimap

hello i am trying to make a map containing objects as the following : class Employee >>dervied from Employee : are the following classes : Worker , Manager and ViceManage.
in my map i want to have the object Employee sorted by his ID which is char*
i tried to create a map like this:`

```
multimap<const string,Employee*> t1
t1<string,Employee>::iterator myIterator;
Date e(17,6,1985);
Address a("somecity","somestreet",15,12);
ViceManager* d = new ViceManager("John","Doh","035845778", e,a,"03-9458353",10000,85,"gsdasda");
t1.insert(make_pair(d->GetId(),d));
myIterator=t1.begin();
myIterator->comp_value->PrintEmployee();
```

i got alot of problems in my code i would very much like to hear what you guys want to say thx in advance

Comment: how should i define my map and how can i use a iterator to be able to use methods like `PrintEmployee()` which exist inside the object  ViceManager

Comment: Why `multimap` instead of `map`? Why `d` is `ViceManager *`, not `Employee *`? What is `comp_value`? I would suggest to first trim down the `Employee` or `ViceManager` class, make the map work, and then expand it back. Also, please see if you can post full C++ code that compiles cleanly.

Comment: What's the signature of `GetId()`. Does it return `string` or `char*`?

Comment: "i got alot of problems in my code" - Generally it helps to actually describe the problems rather than just dump code and hope that people notice whatever might be causing unknown problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, iterator is a type which is typedef'ed in `multimap` template class in your case. So you need to write the following:

```
multimap<const string,Employee*>::iterator myIterator;
```

As for second part of your question, you could add a new field in the `Employee` class that will identify employee type (Worker , Manager and ViceManage). Then cast depending on that field:

```
if ( myIterator->type == VICE_MANAGER ) 
  static_cast<ViceManager*>(*myIterator->second)->PrintEmployee();
```

If your classes are polymorphic (which is a preferred solution) you could call `PrintEmployee` without additional cast:

```
myIterator->second->PrintEmployee();
```

Comment: I prefer

`typedef t1::iterator myIterator;`

so that I don't repeat the map's types in two places. (Single-Point-of-Truth or Dont-Repeat-Yourself) [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Point_of_Truth]

Comment: Why are you suggesting downcasting before calling `PrintEmployee`? If its behaviour is different for different employee types, then it should be virtual.

Comment: @Mike Seymour, yes I missed that `PrintEmployee` is a member of the `Employee` class.

Answer (score 3):

Really, only two errors there, both related to iterators.

```
multimap<const string,Employee*> t1;
multimap<string,Employee*>::iterator myIterator; //Note the corrected iterator type
Date e(17,6,1985);
Address a("somecity","somestreet",15,12);
Employee* d = new ViceManager("John","Doh","035845778", e,a,"03-9458353",10000,85,"gsdasda");
t1.insert(make_pair(d->GetId(),d));
myIterator=t1.begin();
myIterator->second->PrintEmployee(); //Note the way of accessing the value
```

I notice that this code isn't really taking advantage of the map functionality, I assume that's for other sections of the code.

Editing to fix some mistakes I missed